# How to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked a question: [Explanation of transistor amplifying action](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100594/explanation-of-transistor-amplifying-action). I wrote my question very specifically by highlighting the main points which I do not understand but even I have not got any useful answer.

I don't know why someone downvoted my question. Perhaps the downvote is due to the grammatical or formatting mistakes; I can just speculate.

I want to ask more questions but I am afraid I would be again downvoted and banned.

> Please help me how should I ask my questions.

I have more question to ask like on \$LC\$ tuned circuit and on pull down resister. Please tell me how should I ask these questions.

I also want to ask this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82949/steady-state-of-diffusion-current-in-semiconductors on this website because I think on physic.SE people are not so much familiar with solid state electronics. When I was using my previous account I cross-posted this question on this website but it get downvoted and soon deleted by the community moderator.

> So should I cross-post this question from phys.SE?

---

This is a response to @ChrisLaplante.
 [My comment](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/how-to-ask-a-question/3411#comment7588_3411) was not for the whole SE network(i.e. every SE website), it is only for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  Although my comment has been edited by someone its essence is pretty much same as before.
 I had an account on this website which I have deleted. With my previous account I asked some questions which were downvoted silently. I **did not know** why my questions were downvoted that's why I could not improve them. I was banned to ask more questions. I do not have enough knowledge to answer Engineering questions that's why I could not lift the ban. Once I was banned on Phys.SE too but by posting answers I lifted that ban. I have made a new account here and asked two questions. My two question are not well received by the community and are downvoted. Now I know why my questions were downvoted in my previous account \$-\$ Because I did make some grammatical and formatting mistakes. But now I do not know why these two present questions are still remain downvoted although a gentle person has corrected the grammatical and formatting mistakes in it. Perhaps on this website people forget after downvoting.
 Now let's come to the point. I am not mistaken this website. It is a FACT.  On http://math.stackexchange.com I did make the same grammatical and formatting mistakes(like not capitalizing the word "I") but nobody downvoted for this reason. Math.SE is very good website there are very friendly people, they have given me very useful answers. This website should learn from Math.SE.
Do you know what most of the people do here(on EE.SE)? They downvote silently and walk away. They do not tell what's wrong in the post. They do not even bother whether the OP has corrected the error in his question or not. 
 Like any country is known by the behaviour of its people, any website is known by the behaviour of its users. If majority of the people(users) of a community(website) discriminate(and humiliate) on the basis of language then that community(website) will be called "*A Linguistic discriminating community(website)*"
 I did not came here to dissrespect anyone. I came here to learn and to ask questions. I did not want to make things personal but people here have prejudices for me, they made things personal. Yes I am an Engg. student and never understood any of my subjects. You know why? Because human race is alike, people behave in real life the same they do on any internet website. Throughout my academic carrier I have always been mocked because I ask questions which are difficult to understand and difficult to answer. My teachers always say: Your question is nonsense, it is not understandable, you are confused and confusing me too, etc etc. But the truth is my teachers do not have the qualification to answer my questions.
  No one can take away my right to learn. I can self study like I did in school time. 
Mr. Lathrop is right - I do not belong here. This website is an English based website for intelligent students.

Comment: I edited my question because i think my question is been misinterpreted. I do not expect for SE system to teach me the engineering subjects. I want to ask some questions on this site. As my question are related to engineering stream so they should be On-topic here. My questions usually get downvoted. I want to know what's the reason behind these downvotes so i could present rest of my questions as clearly as possible. Please do not deviate from the question. If there are some personal issues with me then its ok i will not become a part of this site. Regards.

Comment: One thing that would *greatly* help is to observe proper capitalization rules. I realize English probably isn't your first language, but bad formatting can be a contributing factor to people not wanting to put forth effort to understand your question.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I have responded to your comment in my question. It is clear most of the users(not everyone) here downvote the posts which have bad English.

Comment: For the record, I don't down-vote strictly due to grammar or capitalization problems. Those are pet peeves, but I base my votes on the *validity* and *quality* of the question (or answer). I overlook (and usually correct) English where possible, but if the question makes no sense or isn't salvageable, shows little or no effort, etc. then a down-vote is warranted.

Comment: @JYelton Thanks a lot for the edits that you made in my posts. you don't have to justify anything. I realized that I had made this mistake in my all posts on other SE sites and I have edited them.

Comment: @anupam no, not most, just the same few cranky farts.

Comment: [This](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) site might be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have [asked this before](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3287/4512), and apparently learned nothing from the answers.

You just [asked another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/102258/4512) on the main site, and it's full of the same things you were told not to do.  I did give a brief answer, but with so many wrong statements, invalid assumptions, and overall sloppiness, it's no surprise it is getting downvoted.  All the problems make it difficult to answer because a lot of stuff would have to be unraveled first before the context for a meaningful answer could be established, let alone actually answering the question.

In short, you were banned from asking questions for a good reason.  You tried to weasel around the ban by creating a new account.  That's probably against the rules in the first place.  However, you haven't cleaned up your act, which is even worse from my point of view (the moderators may take a particularly dim view of creating another account to circumvent a ban).

On a separate topic, you say that you are about to graduate with a degree in electrical engineering, but yet you are asking how a voltage divider works.  You need to seriously think about your career plans, and take your education seriously - including how you're learning (or *not* learning) from your questions **here**.

Comment: I accept your original answer. You are right I do not belong here and I never did. It is not this website who ostracize me. This is I who leaves this discriminating English website. I will learn English one day but I do speak a second language. Regards

Comment: @Anupam: Please don't mistake Olin's attitude for that of the website (or network) as a whole

Comment: @Chris: At least 7 others agree with me.  SE is launching new sites in other languages, but this site is in English.  While non-native English speakers do get some slack, the problem here was this user was told several times some of the things he was doing wrong, but refused to do anything about it.  Using the wrong tense of a verb or the occasional misspelling can be overlooked because these things can be hard to get right.  However, there is no excuse for the easy and universal rules like capitalizing first letters of sentences and the word "I".

Comment: @OlinLathrop; I understand your frustration, but nevertheless there *are* users on here who are willing to work with non-native speakers to improve their questions (regardless of how many times they make capitalization or spelling mistakes). At the end of the day, we're building a reference site. So, if I can fix the grammar on an otherwise great question which will help future visitors, I'll do it, every time. Anyway, it seems the core problem with this user was his questions were poorly formatted & had bad assumptions. His poor grammar and capitalization problems only added fuel to the fire.

Comment: @Chris: Editing a sloppy post is a short term fix but usually causes more long term problems. Telling the OP what is wrong so he can fix it is fine, but doing it for him only teaches that he doesn't have to care, and he will be back doing the same thing again. That was precisely the problem here. This guy was told what was wrong, but never went back and fixed things and kept doing the same things in new posts. This site isn't for everyone. To keep quality up we need to shed those that can't be bothered to take some care, rather than perpetually cleaning up behind them.

Comment: @OlinLathrop; I'm certainly not making excuses for *this* user. I was speaking more broadly; you have to understand that your opinion regarding editing and content policing in general is completely opposite to the goals of the site/network. See this question, for instance; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87611/to-edit-or-not-to-edit . I know you won't budge in this regard, but I will ask you to stop standing in the way of those who are willing to edit posts. E.g.: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/flagging-history-is-not-showing-up#comment7587_3413,

Comment: @Chris: I have no means to prevent others from editing posts, so talk of standing in their way makes no sense.  Otherwise, I have a right to express my opinion, just as you are doing here.  Your actions are hurting this site.  Clearly you don't agree with that.  However, you're just going to have to get over the fact I do agree with it.

Comment: @Olin; Impeding is not the same as preventing. Regardless, for some reason you believe that your way is better than how *all* the other sites do it. But like you say, you are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante Olin just thinks he knows better then the sum of all all sites experience.

Answer (score 2):

For your original question ban I posted [this answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3288/17064) and some time later I thought to check if you had edited any of your original posts and I couldn't see any edits or other positive activity. Apparently asking new questions is important to you but you couldn't be bothered to fix up any old content. With regard to cross-posting see:

[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Who knows why your new question got downvoted, possibly because it seems to be a few questions rolled into one or maybe because someone thought the Physics.SE answer(s) were satisfactory. You could ask a Physics.SE mod to consider your other question for migration - I'm not sure of the guidelines in that regard but as it looks like you've been suspended to "cool down" on Physics.SE for a while I'm not sure you could even flag it.

Comment: I am having hard time in finding my old posts. On 23feb/2014 i deleted my previous account. Believe me i had made some edits. You are incorrectly writting in your answer"I couldn't see any edits". When i do not write my question in detail people say your question is very unclear. When i write them in detail people say you are asking multiple questions. I just want to know what the heck that circuit is. I i hadn't written the specific points on which i have confusion anybody woud downvote that and you would say :"probably your question is too-broad it is not specific"

Comment: "_someone thought the Physics.SE answer(s) were satisfactory._". Let's be literal for the time being. On phys.SE this question is already deleted by community mod(because it was downvoted) so i didn't literally cross-posted. I written my question incorrectly on this so i am going to edit my question.